# Google search result snippet returning "Loading. ×Sorry to interrupt. CSS Error. Refresh."

Tags: google-search

Does anyone know what could cause Google search results to return

> Loading. ×Sorry to interrupt. CSS Error. Refresh.

as the snippet for one of the pages for our web site?

I've also searched this exact same phrase on Google, and a bunch of sites returned with the same snippet. But searching for what causes this returned no results unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the page’s HTML:

```html
<div class="" id="auraErrorMask">
  <div class="auraErrorBox" id="auraError">
    <span><a class="close" id="dismissError">×</a>Sorry to interrupt</span>
    <div id="auraErrorMessage">CSS Error</div>
    <div id="auraErrorStack"></div>
    <div class="auraErrorFooter"><a href="?" id="auraErrorReload">Refresh</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without JavaScript, it’s the only content of the page. Maybe Googlebot didn’t execute JavaScript when crawling the page, or maybe the JavaScript files couldn’t get loaded. With JavaScript, the bot would have indexed the page with the intended content and then shown a different, more relevant snippet from the page.

It probably comes from the UI framework [Aura](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura) (for Salesforce).

Comment: Oh interesting. Thanks! Will look into that.